# local variable 'data' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, blogs

UnboundLocalError at /post/
local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
Request Method:
POST
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/
Django Version:
1.11.3
Exception Type:
UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:
local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
Exception Location:
D:\website\formapp\views.py in index, line 56

```
def index(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Postform(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        f=form.save(commit=False)
        f.user=request.user
        f.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/post/')
else:
    form = Postform()
    data=Post.objects.order_by('-date_created')
return render(request,'home2.html',{'form':form,'data':data})
```

---

```
class Postform(forms.ModelForm):
pic=models.FileField()
vid=models.FileField()
class Meta:
    model=Post
    #fields=['title','content','pic'] 
    fields='__all__'
```

---

```
<form action=' ' method = 'POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<h3>Title:</h3> {{form.title}}<br><br>
<h3>Content:</h3> {{form.content}}<br><br>
<h3>Pic: </h3>{{form.pic}}<br>
<button type= 'submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-md'>Save</button>
<br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: If the `request.method` is not `POST` your local variable `data` (which you use in the `return` of yor `index()` function) never gets assigned, hence the error.

Comment: I think you have that backwards.  `data` is undefined when the method _is_ `POST`.

Comment: The sample code has invalid indentation. This would result in a `SyntaxError` and not run. Please edit the question so that it contains valid python code.

Answer (score 1):

If `form.is_valid()` returns `False`, you have to assign a value to `data`.

```
def index(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Postform(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            f=form.save(commit=False)
            f.user=request.user
            f.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/post/')
    else:
        form = Postform()

    data=Post.objects.order_by('-date_created') # take this out of the `else` block.
    return render(request,'home2.html',{'form':form,'data':data})
```